# Google Maps works in simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, google-maps

Google Maps works in iPhone simulator, when I run my project on device, it is not working.

Here is error description:

> CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path
>   '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/01B85FB4-C777-467D-9E61-92B4B3240B91/demo/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'

Answer (score 0):

Add -**ObjC** to "`Other Linker Flags`"

```
(Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags).
```

This solved it for me.

After I added this flag I received some errors regarding missing symbols (such as _`CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey`).

I added the `Accelerate` and `CoreBluetooth` frameworks in `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.`

Comment: you got your solution or not

Answer (score 0):

try this link  please see https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8524 for information about debugging

This has been fixed in 1.10.4.

Comment: try this 1.10.4 has been fixed this issue.

Comment: pleaze tell me solution here,may be link not longer avaible

Comment: which ver you are using

Comment: rewrote the whole schema, and when I run the code I got rid of those warnings from core data.

Comment: This issue is fixed in the new update of Google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases?hl=en Check this Link and update your local repositories

Comment: i try to again but 1.10.3 is downloading.what bto do to install to download 1.10.5 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94063/discussion-between-sudheer-kumar-and-infinite-loop).